# Error in if (length(scores.temp) == 1 && scores.temp == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I'm trying to ampute a dataset in order to compare different imputation methods, but I'm getting this error:

> Error in if (length(scores.temp) == 1 && scores.temp == 0) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Here a reproducible example:

```
library(mice)
A <- matrix(c(rep(4,100),rep(5,100),rep(3,100),rep(7,100),rep(8,100),rep(9,100),rep(2,100)), nrow = 20, byrow = F)

A_miss <- ampute(A)
```

Comment: I forgot to say that 'ampute' is a function from package 'mice'.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even with a square matrix.

Comment: Try ampute(A, mech = "MCAR"). I am able to generate

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue with the way that `ampute` standardizes scores for amputing data. If you look at the source code of the `ampute` function, you will find there is an embedded function used to sum the scores for each missing pattern. If the argument `std` in `ampute` is `TRUE`, this embedded score summing function tries to center and *scale* (i.e., take the standard deviation) the scores. The error occurs when only one row is in the score matrix because, if you try to take the standard deviation of each column in a one row matrix, you get nothing but NaN. Luckily, there is an easy fix, just set `std` to `FALSE`. This shouldn't impact the structure of the amputed data, since scaling is just an affine transform of the weights that are used to induce missingness.

```r
library(mice)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mice'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     cbind, rbind
A <- matrix(c(rep(4,100),rep(5,100),rep(3,100),rep(7,100),rep(8,100),rep(9,100),rep(2,100)), nrow = 20, byrow = F)

A_miss <- ampute(A, std = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>